# How to reference a solution from macro

Tags: visual-studio-macros

I want to use this macro to format my code:
http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/Format-Solution.aspx

I guess I need to the change line:

```
Dim sol As Solution = DTE.Solution
```

My solution appears in Visual Studio 2010 like so:
**Solution 'ABC.Mmc.Client' (16 Projects)**

I've tried changing the line to:

```
Dim sol As Solution = ABC.Mmc.Client.Solution
```

but that doesn't work.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DTE.Solution` refers to the currently loaded solution. Leave the code as it is, load your solution, and you're good to go.